# hyperref title page problem in pdf

Tags: hyperref, pdf

When I use `hyperref`, my title page is number 1 of `pdf`, also the second page is page number one of `pdf`.

[image]

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} %\textsubscript{}
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage[margin=30mm,hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=10pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage} 

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE some text}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large some text}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large some text}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries some text}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
\Large \emph{some text \\some text}\\ [30mm]
%\textsc{}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\large \today}\\[2cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics[width=50mm,keepaspectratio]{}\\[0.5cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
\end{titlepage}

\section{Intro}

some text  some text  some text some text

\section{2}

\newpage
\section{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Looks like a resetting of a page number in between, but this is only a guess, since, well, you did not provide a compilable version of your document

Comment: This isn't compilable by far  -- no `\documentclass`, no relevant packages and with errors!

Comment: Now is more like my final document.

Comment: that is what `titlepage` does, You can remove it and use `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: @HenriqueSilva so many edits and still not compilable ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I can compile it.

Comment: @HenriqueSilva: Yes, the fourth or fifth version is compilable finally

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry about that, first time here, and wasn't prepared...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the page number does not appear on the title page, then `\thepage` can be redefined to show something different as `1`, e.g. `Title` or `0`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{Title}
My Title.
\end{titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

If the page number appears on the title page, then a different interface can be used: `\thispdfpagelabel` sets the page label for the current page. `\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}` inside the group disables the automatic page anchor in the environment to prevent a duplicate destination error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispdfpagelabel{Title}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
My Title.
\end{titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```